# Kubernetes LoadBalancer best practise: avoid NodePort?

Tags: kubernetes

We are trying to find and implement best practises for Kubernetes and LoadBalancer typed services.

We found an entry that an open NodePort is a bad-practise if you use a LoadBalancer.
Kubernetes now always creates a NodePort too, when we use `type: LoadBalancer`

`service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  port: 30111`

I cannot find a hint in the documentation why this happens, if this is normal or how to avoid a NodePort here.

What's the reason Kubernetes always creates a NodePort too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a normal behavior.
From [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/#publishing-services-service-types):

> LoadBalancer: Exposes the service externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer. **NodePort** and **ClusterIP** services, to which the external load balancer will route, are automatically created.

The problem configuring an external load balancer and a NodePort service type, is that you would be balancing requests between the nodes twice: one time at the external load balancer and another time at svc Kubernetes level.

As far as I know, using the LoadBalancer service type Kubernetes avoids doing this and at least in EKS uses the NodePort service for health check purposes (target groups).

Comment: Thanks. This means also I should not use LoadBalancer if I do not run my services behind an external Load Balancer?
Why I am able to give the same port to the LB and the NP: `localhost 31000:31000`?